# Написать протокол прикладного уровня

Tags: udp, qt, c++

Нужно написать протокол прикладного уровня, работающий через UDP. Посоветуйте, что почитать по теме, примеры простых протоколов.

Comment: RFC?­­­­­­

Comment: Это слишком общее, хотелось бы конкретики. Я просто хотел посмотреть пример простой реализации) Там уж если не будет понятно - буду спрашивать.

Comment: О, отличная задача. Такой простор для фантазии!

Comment: > хотелось бы конкретики

Если не устраивает совет читать RFC, тогда хотелось бы конкретики в вопросе.

Comment: tftp -- trivial file transfer protocol. Номер rfc не помню, гугл, надеюсь, знает. Из непростых -- смотрите ip-телефонию и всякую мельтимудию

Comment: Да, если не ошибаюсь, Quake3 работает через UDP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что именно не понятно? На базовом уровне UDP это просто sendto/recvfrom.

[Well-Known UNIX TCP and UDP Services](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Networking/Networking_Tips/BASICS_Well-Known_UNIX_Services.shtml) попробуйте посмотреть что-либо из них.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой пример смотрите у Стивенса "Unix: разработка сетевых приложений". Простые эхо-клиент и эхо-сервер через UDP.